# Minecraft Online Play

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

One day I tried to play in a LAN world via Hamachi. But when I gave her the IP she said it didn't work.
Then she gave me her ip, but it didn't work also! My version is 1.7.2 and hers is 1.7.2 also. 
What do I need to do to establish a connection?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if single player networking works outside our home, but you can use lan at your home, or do this:

1. Try download a Minecraft server from [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/en/download/server) (or [here, 1.7.2](https://launcher.mojang.com/mc/game/1.7.10/server/952438ac4e01b4d115c5fc38f891710c4941df29/server.jar))
2. Try [ipchicken.com](http://ipchicken.com/), I guess you're using IPv4 IP (IPv4: 192.168.1.something), try to send her the IP you'll see on ipchicken.com

Answer (score 1):

Hamachi uses a custom IP.

Give your IPv4 IP that's shown in the Hamachi app, not in the ipconfig command!!!

Comment: This is the correct answer if you're suing Hamachi.  MC is going to display the local address, but it's unlikely to see the Hamachi address.  Your computer can see both of them though.  Just make sure to include the port number at the end if there is one.

Comment: Thanks everyone but none of this helps works.